# What operations should I put into Platform.runLater()?

Tags: java, javafx, concurrency

Lately I encountered some issues with code that asynchonously updates GUI. I then came across [this article](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/javafx/javafx-concurrency-example/), which shined some light on the problem - I was not using `Platform.runLater()` to update my GUI components, however, consider the original code:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    private TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
    private Label statusLabel = new Label("Not Started...");
    private Button startButton = new Button("Start");
    private Button exitButton = new Button("Exit");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) {
        startButton.setOnAction(event -> startTask());
        exitButton.setOnAction(event -> stage.close());
        HBox buttonBox = new HBox(5, startButton, exitButton);
        VBox root = new VBox(10, statusLabel, buttonBox, textArea);
        root.setStyle("-fx-padding: 10;" +
                "-fx-border-style: solid inside;" +
                "-fx-border-width: 2;" +
                "-fx-border-insets: 5;" +
                "-fx-border-radius: 5;" +
                "-fx-border-color: blue;");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 300);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("A simple Concurrency Example");
        stage.show();
    }

    private void startTask() {
        Runnable task = this::runTask;
        Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(task);
        backgroundThread.setDaemon(true);
        backgroundThread.start();
    }

    private void runTask() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            try {
                String status = "Processing " + i + " of " + 10;
                statusLabel.setText(status);
                textArea.appendText(status + "\n");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problematic part is the `runTask()` method. The article explains that instead of simply using `statusLabel.setText(status)`, I should use `Platform.runLater(() -> statusLabel.setText(status));`. That makes sense to me.

What doesn't make sense, however, is why I don't have to apply the same logic to `textArea` updates? Notice the fifth line of `runTask()` method - the `textArea.appendText(status + "\n");` part. Why it doesn't give me an exception (`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread`) about modifying an FX component from non-FX thread, since it's clearly a way of updating GUI FX component? What operations should I put inside the `Platform.runLater()` and what operations do now have to be there?

Comment: The operations that need be executed on the JavaFX application thread have not changed, but many checks for the thread executing logic that should not be executed on a background thread have been removed; Afaik they were never done consistently in every place where they were needed... What kind of operation needs to be done on the javafx application thread? Basically every operation that modifies one of the properies of a node that has been added to a scene, even if this happens indirectly (e.g. through listeners to properties). There are some exceptions, but they are documented in the javadoc

Comment: @fabian so that means that I actually should've also wrapped `textArea.appendText(status + "\n")` in `Platform.runLater()`?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: You can, of course, place both statements (statusLabel.setText and textArea.appendText) in a single Platform.runLater call.  By the way, when a thread is interrupted, it means someone explicitly wants you to halt what you’re doing, so you should exit your `runTask` method as cleanly as possible when catching InterruptedException.

Comment: the blog post is simply wrong - commented over there ...

Comment: looks like critics isn't wanted on https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/ (my comment was deleted) - so I would suggest to take everything on that blog with a grain of salt, might be good or not .. and the cited blog above definitely is extremely bad!

Answer (score -1):

Run later will interfere more or less with the UI Thread. The execution will be queued in the UI thread. When you have a thread sleep or a long calculation the UI will freeze. You can use it for **simple** tasks. But in your case I do recommend it, because it is only a "set-operation".

Generally you should use **Observable properties** and bind them to the UI when possible. **Then you don't need to do** anything of the "Thread" and "Queuing" and "RunLater" operations.

When the WHOLE operation is needed to executed with the "run later", and the calculation would be time costly, you should look, for what you can run later or use a different Mechanism.

But when you just add something with out run laterform a difficult or longer calculation from another thread, an exception will pop up.

So what you want is to update the UI-Elements when it is needed and the new values are calculated or provided by whatever mechanism.

Here the way to go with Properties:

```
StringProperty text = new SimpleStringProperty("Hello");

Label label = new Label();

label.getTextProperty().bind(text);
```

Now whenever you Update **text** from another Thread, the update will automatically occur in the UI without Run Later.

If there is no way around:

What you could (in the case of more costly operations) do is have a queue that contains all the executions of updates for the view that come asynchronously. And execute the changes only in the JavaFX Thread.

You should use the Animationtimer for that.

```
//thread safe queue
Queue<Runnable> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>();
```

Now the approach with `runLater`:

```
Platform.runLater(()->{
    while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
        queue.remove().run();
    }
});
```

And the approach with the AnimationTimer.

```
AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {
    @Override
    public void handle(long now) {
        //Whatever condition or how many changes you would make at one tick
        //In this case we just run all "updates" in that tick.
        // I would recommend it, you could update 100 things each tick
        while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
            queue.remove().run();
        }

    }
};
timer.start();
```

Then have a thread that would calculate something and when it's done it adds the new change to the queue. Or sleeps or waits for a response etc.

```
private void startTask() {
    Runnable task = this::runTask;
    Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(task);
    backgroundThread.setDaemon(true);
    backgroundThread.start();
}

private void runTask() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        try {
            String status = "Processing " + i + " of " + 10;
            //Add the new change as a Runnable here
            //It will be run in the in the next update of the UI 

            tasks.add(()->{
                statusLabel.setText(status);

                textArea.appendText(status + "\n");
           });

            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE**

It still depends for what purpose you are going to use it.
Those are just two approaches.
When you only update declared values, you could also use Property Bindings.
(StringProperty in your case)

And I would personally always go with the AnimationTimer. 
RunLater decides when it is "fine" with queuing the Runnable. With the Animationtimer, you can be sure it is executed each tick, when a update is needed.

You could also Store all the updates and then do a "poll" of the new Values each tick.

**TASK**

When you know exactly where you want to put which value you should use Task and bind it the the UI element, that would also work.

```
Label statusLabel = new Label("Not Started...");

Task<String> t = new Task<String>() {

@Override
protected String call() throws Exception {
    int i = 0;
    while(//any condition ... ) {
        i++;
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        updateValue("i is " + i);
    }

    return "last value!";
}
```

```
// now Bind the TextProperty of the Label to the ValueProperty of the  
// Task
statusLabel.getTextproperty().bind(task.getValueProperty());
Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(task);
backgroundThread.start();
```

Comment: why re-invent the wheel? platform.runlater queues the requests for the ui, no need to do it worse than that (your queue effectively condenses all runs into a single run, with higher probability to block the ui thread)

Comment: @kleopatra yes. Thats true. And It depends. 
You could also Use properties, and Bind them. then you don't need a "run later" .
When you have a lot of updates, that are put in a run later, you interfere with the "UI thread" it won't happen when you do it once. 

In C# WPF you have the same issue with **Dispatcher**. 
when you for example have a game and a server that sends updates. I would only use Bindings.

When you have thousands of changes an put them all into a run later, it would cause issues with the flow the of the UI.

Comment: if you have thousands of changes each wrapped individually into a runlater, you probably have a problem elsewhere ;) Not sure what you mean by _use properties and bind them_ - generally binding doesn't make a difference except when update notification is, which is guaranteed for observables of Task/Service f.i. (which I assume is what you intended to say :) otherwise it's plain wrong.

Comment: @kleopatra in JFX you have Properties wich are Observable wich every UI element has and I learned, that you should minimize runLater() operations or Other UI-Thread interference. You can use it, but its not good. The UI Thread should not decide when it applies a task that contains a change. The UI thread is looking up changes in the UI-component and renders them. You should only change the Model and the Change in the Model should notify the view representation of the Model. That is my understanding of dealing with UI threads. When you have tiny changes maybe you should use runLater().

Comment: still not clear: changing of model properties often happen off the fx thread, right? if so, you cant bind them to ui properties because you would change the bound ui property off the fx thread as well. The only option is to somehow switch the off-fx change into the on-fx realm (either by runlater or placing a task/worker/service or any other way that guarantees to promote the change of threads)